# What is the best way to check if a column contains any of the keywords

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table of keywords

Keywords:

```
KeyID | Keyword
 1      Small
 2      Medium
 3      Large
 4      XXLarge
```

Then I have another table "Logs" that has over 100 000 records.

Logs:

```
LogId | Description
1        blah blah.. Medium blah
2        dsdms    Large whatever
```

I would like to add another column as KeyId in Logs table and then go through each Description to find if it contains the Keyword, then set the KeyId to correct KeyID from Keywords table for that row entry.

What is the fastest way to achieve this?

Comment: The fastest way is to use SQL Server's full text search functionality to generate FTS indexes. Anything else will be slow to code and slow to execute

Comment: What do you mean by "fastest"? Do you mean that you have to do this *one time* only and want to get this done quick and dirty without setting too much up? Or do you want to setup a sturdy process which can achieve the above over and over again for new incoming data and steadily growing tables?

Comment: Just curious, what do you do in case of a Description like:  "blah blah Large.. blah Medium... blah blah XXLarge Small"?

Comment: It will be one time only process. any way would be accepted. I wonder if it is possible with query or console application is required. If possible how?

Comment: the description only contains one of the keywords @JFM

Answer (score 0):

I tried in following way. Please Check:

```
create table one(
keyid int,
keyword varchar(10)
)


insert into one values (1,'Small')
insert into one values (2,'Medium')
insert into one values (3,'Large')
insert into one values (4,'XXLarge')

create table two(
logid int,
description varchar(100))

insert into two values ('1','blah blah.. Medium blah')
insert into two values ('2','dsdms    Large whatever')


alter table two add  keyid int
```

And this is the query as per your requirement

```
declare @query varchar(800),@keyid int,@keyword  varchar(100),@description varchar(max),@LOGID INT

declare d cursor for 
select keyid,keyword from one
open d
fetch next from d into @keyid,@keyword
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin

declare c cursor for
select DESCRIPTION,LOGID from two
open c
fetch next from c into @description, @logid
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

set @query='if exists(select * from two where upper(description) like ''%' +upper(@keyword)+'%'' and logid='+cast(@LOGID as varchar(max))+' )
begin
update two set keyid=(select keyid from one where upper(keyword)=''' +upper(@keyword)+''') where logid='+cast(@LOGID as varchar(max))+'
end'
print @query
exec (@query)

fetch next from c into @description, @logid
end
close c
deallocate c

fetch next from d into @keyid,@keyword
end
close d
deallocate d

select * from two
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the sample data @RanjanaGhimire provided for us (thank you very much for that) the following query might suffice:

```
update t
set keyid = o.keyid
from dbo.one as o
    cross join dbo.two as t
where charindex(o.keyword, t.description) > 0;
```